# PHP - Operations with date/time

Tags: php

I'm trying with to date/time php functions. I would like to do the basic arithmetic operations(addition, subtraction...). I have read that there are various function to do it.

I'm beginning with DateTime and date_diff.

```
<?php

$time1 = new DateTime ('08:10:20');

$time2 = new DateTime ('10:02:30');

$result = date_diff($time1, $time2)->format('H:i:s');

echo $result;

?>
```

After run it, it show:

[image]

Please Could you help me?

Comment: Try to change `format('HH:MM:SS');` to `format('H:i:s');`

Comment: @Vincent G it doesn't work fine. The result: H:i:s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way will be object oriented:

```
$time1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '08:10:20');
$time2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '10:02:30');

$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $interval->format('%H:%i:%s'); // print 01:52:10
```

I highly discourage using procedural process :

```
date_diff($time1, $time2);
```

Use object oriented as much as possible:

```
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: It working fine! Thanks! Could you explain me the expression: 'DateTime::createFromFormat

Comment: You was trying to create date from  : "08:10:20" but you need to define that in which format you are giving the date(or time in your case). So you need to use createFromFormat() function and give first parameter as the format you are using for giving your date or time that is: H:i:s,

FOr example if you would give date like: 30-08-2016 12:52:08, your format would be: d-m-Y H:i:s and you would use:

$time1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '30-08-2016 12:52:08'); and soon.

Answer (score 2):

`date_diff` will returns a `DateInterval` object. You can read [here](http://php.net/manual/it/dateinterval.format.php) the characters that you can use inside the format parameter:

```
$result = date_diff($time1, $time2)->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

> Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%).

Comment: It does work good and a right answer but object oriented method is always recommended over procedural wherever possible. I highly discourage using procedural process : date_diff($time1, $time2); We should use object oriented as much as possible: $interval = $time1->diff($time2);

Comment: why? what the hell are you talking about?

Comment: For those who has no idea for difference between procedural and OOP:

I believe you are not familiar with Object Oriented Programmin(OOP). Please read following article i found on normal search for clarification between "Procedural" and "OOP" programming difference as I dont have time to explain that:

https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/php-procedural-vs-object-oriented/33753

Comment: Really? Are you serous? I'm curious, do you think that your code and OP's code is different in any way? Why?

Comment: I already commented that your code will also work same but OOP is better than procedural and I posted the link for you to see why. Please visit it.

PS. my code is OOP and yours is procedural, that's the difference.

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong format string

try

```
format('H:i:s')
```

After Edit :

Try this

```
    <?php

$time1 = new DateTime ('08:10:20');

$time2 = new DateTime ('10:02:30');

$result = date_diff($time1, $time2)->format('%h:%i:%s');

echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

> Each format character must be prefixed by a percent sign (%)

```
$time1 = new DateTime('08:10:20');
$time2 = new DateTime('10:02:30');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $interval->format('%h:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('08:10:06')->format('HH:MM:SS');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('08:10:06')->format('HH:MM:SS');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('HH:MM:SS');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$to_time = strtotime("10:02:30");
$from_time = strtotime("08:10:20");
$time_diff = $to_time - $from_time;
echo gmdate('H:i:s', $time_diff);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/671723)**

Comment: it works! Thank you. @Dave which is the best way using strtotime or date time?

Answer (score 0):

Use this  `$result = $time2->diff($time1)->format('%h:%i:%s');` or `date_diff($time1, $time2)->format('%h:%i:%s');`

```
$time1 = new DateTime ('08:10:20');

$time2 = new DateTime ('10:02:30');
$time1->format('H:i:s');
$time2->format('H:i:s');
$result = $time2->diff($time1)->format('%h:%i:%s');

echo $result;
```

Output

```
1:52:10
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to find the differnce in seconds. also you can use this to process date time paramenters according to your need.

```
<?php

function secondsConverter($dateTime1,$dateTime2)
{
    $hour=abs($dateTime1['hour']-$dateTime2['hour'])*3600;
    $minutes=abs($dateTime1['minute']-$dateTime2['minute'])*60;
    $seconds=abs($dateTime1['second']-$dateTime2['second']);

   return $hour+$minutes+$seconds;
}

$dateTime1=date_parse("10:00:00.5");
$dateTime2=date_parse("11:00:00.5");
echo secondsConverter($dateTime1,$dateTime2);

?>
```